# Problem mounting my external hard disk

Tags: command-line, mount, hard-drive

I'm unable to access any data from my external hard disk, because I can't mount it.

```
namrata@fighter:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 125f:a31a A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

namrata@fighter:~$ sudo fdisk -l

 Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
 Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 Disk identifier: 0x799123c5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1   *          63   102398309    51199123+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda2       102398371   312580095   105090862+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
  /dev/sda5       102398373   204796619    51199123+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda6       204797952   262823463    29012756    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda7       310505472   312580095     1037312   82  Linux swap / Solaris
  /dev/sda8       262823936   310503423    23839744   83  Linux

 namrata@fighter:~$ sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /media/external
 mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

What should be my fs type? Or is there a different way to access my external hardisk?

Comment: mount can detect the fs type itself. Try to mount it without specifing the type like this: `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/external`. Does that work?

Comment: /dev/sda is your internal hard drive. Your external hard drive isn't listed there, even though lsusb finds it connected to usb port. It might be a toast

Answer (score 0):

I found a link with several solutions, one of the latter is a program that may give you a work around. The pmount software may be a fast solution, if you try it let me know if it works please.

---

```
sudo apt-get install pmount


pmount <device> [ label ]
```

e.g

```
pmount /dev/sda1
```

to unmount

```
pumount
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I am more of a noob but the pmount software looked like a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

First boot to Windows (as you seem to have a dual boot system) and:

```
chkdsk /f X:
```

where X is the drive letter of the FAT partition.

then mount with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/external
```

(no options)

and that should fix it...

Comment: Fabby, notice that OP boots from /dev/sda, while OP's external hard-drive probably should be something like /dev/sdb

Comment: @Serg I did.  ;-)  But in his example he tries to mount that particular partition...  Hopefully, we'll get some **feed-back, please?** when he/she/it reads this answer...  >:-)

Comment: @namrata-manglani: see above.  Could you provide some feed-back?